# Failed upgrade from SDL Tridion 2011 to 2011 SP1

Tags: 2011, 2011-sp1, upgrade

I am upgrading from SDL 2011 to SDL 2011 SP1 so as a 1st step I am able to successfully upgrade my DB ,now for step 2 I have started upgrading CMS by running “” after running the installer its says upgrade fails and give below message.

“Access to the path 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Tridion\bin\ChilkatDotNet2.dll_backup' is denied.”

I have cross checked and found that "Full control" is provided to Administration account.

Can you please guide me what went wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This specifies that although you have necessary permissions, but the file `C:\Program Files (x86)\Tridion\bin\ChilkatDotNet2.dll_backup`is still in use by some process. Backing up the DLLs by appending something in their name is always a bad idea, instead you may either take their backup to some other location and delete it or may be you can changes its extension from .dll to something else.

Verify that the the above said dlls is not in use and run the installer again by right clicking and choosing "Run as Administrator"

Comment: Hey Pankaj Thanks for your response, do you mean to say that i just need to backup and remove ChilkatDotNet2.dll_backup" and re run the installer?

Comment: yes..it seems some of your code is still referencing the DLL while you run the installer. I would suggest, possibly take a backup of it somewhere else and delete it. Reset the SDL Tridion CM COM+ app, all tridion services and IIS and then run the installer as Admin